# printf function produces unexpected output

Tags: c

I am trying to execute `printf` function, which is `printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", *w)`

I know how it works, but I couldn't get the right result, which is "true".
This is what I display the variables in `gdb`.
After line 31, I execute:

```
(gdb) n
```

and I expected "true" to be printed.
Instead, I got nothing as you can see.
Why is it behaving like this?

```
31              printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", *w);
6: **w = 116 't'
5: *w = 0x7ffffffd7eb0 "true"
4: w = (char **) 0x7ffffffd76b0
3: **(c->u.word) = 116 't'
2: *(c->u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7eb0 "true"
1: c->u.word = (char **) 0x7ffffffd76b0
(gdb) n
32              while (*++w) // if next character is not null, keep printing.
6: **w = 116 't'
5: *w = 0x7ffffffd7eb0 "true"
4: w = (char **) 0x7ffffffd76b0
3: **(c->u.word) = 116 't'
2: *(c->u.word) = 0x7ffffffd7eb0 "true"
1: c->u.word = (char **) 0x7ffffffd76b0
```

After I execute `(gdb) n` I expected the value of `*w` get printed out. However I got nothing.

Why is it?

**Code**

```
case SIMPLE_COMMAND:
      {
    char **w = c->u.word;
    printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", *w);
    printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", "true");
    while (*++w) // if next character is not null, keep printing.
      printf (" %s", *w); 
    break;
      }
```

**The structure of c->u.word looks like this:**

```
struct command
{
  int status;
  union
  {

    struct command *command[2];

    char **word;

    struct command *subshell_command;
  } u;
};
```

#### EDIT:Another issue detedted

```
printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", "true");
    //abort();
    while (*++w) // if next character is not null, keep printing.
      printf (" %s", *w);
```

When I put abort(); after the printf function, it prints out the right output.
However, when I decomment abort, it does not print out anything.
Also, the line after printf function "while(*++w) causes infinite loop, and I believe that the condition 
evaluates *++w, and I think it evaluates ++w first and * next.

w = w+1;
*w;

How do I get out of this loop?

Comment: Could you post the whole code section?

Comment: Is it right that the printf statements have 2 placeholders but take 3 arguments to be printed? This should result in a warning at the least from the compiler

Comment: * corresponds indent, s corresponds "", and %s corresponds *w. So that's not a problem. I also try printf("%s","true"), and it does not work either.

Comment: printf("%s","true") works for me.

Comment: Wait, then what could be the reason that I don't see any output for this function?

Comment: how does the structure look like?

Comment: char** word is inside of the union u, and the union u is inside of a struct command, and c is a pointer to struct command.

Comment: Are you sure the code gets to this case? I've simulated this code on my pc and it works. Maybe the gdb doesn't print it?

Comment: Why do you have a `%*s` in the printf? Shouldn't it be a `%s`?

Comment: Ok, I figured out that while (*++w) creates infinity loop. After I inserted abort(); before that line, it prints out the right result! Sorry about confusion.

Comment: Now I am dealing with the next line. What's the condition that makes the code get out of the while loop?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show us a short complete example program and its output. (The `gdb` output is not particularly useful.) http://sscce.org/

Comment: try adding a '\n' to your i/o on stdout (which is buffered by default and will hold i/o till it sees a '\n')

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier is difficult to read on the manpages, I have missed the '.' before: 
`printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", *w);` should be `printf ("%.*s%s", indent, "", *w);` and the string should probably end in a '\n' to prevent it from staying buffered on stdout (This is why aborting "fixes" it).

Answer (score 0):

Your `char** w` means that `w` is a pointer to a character pointer, not to a character.
So when you do `while (*++w)` you are not advancing over characters, but over whole strings (hoping that the last one is NULL).
Typically you see code like this in `main(int argc, char** argv)` where the array of strings is terminated with a NULL pointer.
Otherwise your loop will crash.

Also, do you actually mean to do `while(*w++)` so that you'll print the first one as well?

Answer to comment: suppose you have a main program `main(int argc, char** argv)` and you invoke the program with this command line:

```
myprogram one two three
```

then inside the program you will see that

```
argv[0] is "myprogram"
argv[1] is "one"
argv[2] is "two"
argv[3] is "three"
argv[4] == NULL  so it is a null pointer. It does not point to a string.
```

so if you have this loop

```
while(char* w = *argv++){
    printf("%s\n", w);
}
```

you should see

```
myprogram
one
two
three
```

The reason it stops is `w` picks up the null pointer, which is 0.

Comment: while (*++w) // if next character is not null, keep printing.
   printf (" %s", *w); So I want to keep printing out. By the way, value of *++w is definitely not null and it cause the problem. How do I initially set up the null value if it is not assigned by any element?

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you print stuff with `printf` it just gets placed in a buffer.  You won't actually see anything until the buffer is flushed.  You can flush the buffer explicitly by calling `fflush(stdout)`, or you can change the buffering mode.  When outputting to a terminal, most C libraries default to line buffered, which will implicitly flush the buffer every time a '\n' (newline) is output, so you might see something if you add a `\n` to the string you are outputting.